# uploading artifacts for maven in apache archiva

Tags: apache, maven, archiva

I am using Spring roo.But i found that roo uses internet to download the maven plugins at first time. To avoid it am trying to use Apache archiva Stand alone.But i don know how can i configure it for maven.Can you help me to solve this

Comment: Why is downloading from the internet a problem? Apache archiva will also do this the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache Archiva can serve the artifacts you need for Spring Roo, but if you do not have an internet connection from the Apache Archiva server then you have to upload the artifacts yourself.

But if you can get the server connected to the internet once, then you can let the archiva server download the artifacts for you, because it can act as a proxy and then caches the artifacts. Once connected to internet, let Spring Roo retrieve the artifacts from the Archiva server. When you have done this one time, archiva should have cached the artifacts. Then you could disconnect it from the internet.

If you want to know how you can configure maven to use the Apache Archiva repository, look at:

http://archiva.apache.org/docs/1.0.1/userguide/using-repository.html